# pyarrow: non-legacy filesystem cannot connect, even though legacy can

Tags: python, pyarrow

When trying to use the non-legacy dataset from pyarrow package (version 0.17.1), i get the `OSError: HDFS connection failed` error when connecting to `hdfs`. However, when i use the legacy one, i can establish the connection without any issues.

i.e. the bellow works:

`filesystem = pa.hdfs.connect(host = 'host_name', kerb_ticket = path_to_kerb_ticket_cache, port = 0)`

but this does not:

`filesystem = pa.fs.HadoopFileSystem(host = 'host_name', kerb_ticket = path_to_kerb_ticket_cache, port = 0)`

Moreover, if i first create connection using the legacy way and then try to connect with the non-legacy way, everything works:

```
filesystem = pa.hdfs.connect(host = 'host_name', kerb_ticket = path_to_kerb_ticket_cache, port = 0)
filesystem = pa.fs.HadoopFileSystem(host = 'host_name', kerb_ticket = path_to_kerb_ticket_cache, port = 0)
```

Any ideas how to properly use pa.fs.HadoopFileSystem?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the legacy connect function and enter the host as `default` it takes the default host from `core-site.xml` (defaultFS). The new HadoopFileSystem call does not do this. Manually entering the host into `HadoopFileSystem` fixed it for me.

e.g. entering the host in this part

`fs.HadoopFileSystem(host='hdfs://your-hdfs-host' ...)`

instead of entering `default`

`fs.HadoopFileSystem(host='default' ...)`

Comment: I tried with host='hdfs://your-hdfs-host' as per your suggestion, but it doesn't help

Comment: Did you replace `your-hdfs-host` with your actual host? You can find it under `defaultFS` in `core-site.xml`.

Comment: I did, but i just got back to this issue today and  it turns out we did not have properly configured CLASSPATH variable. setting it to the hadoop classpath --glob resolved the issue (i guess whether you have to use hdfs classpath --glob or hadoop classpath --glob, as suggested by documentation, depends on how your system is configured).

Comment: Ah yes, I also had to set the classpath. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: I wish they just mentioned in the documentation, that the non-legacy way misses some magic from the legacy version that means now you have to set the classpath while previously it was possible to get it to work without this step